# How to extract the value of a specific key, and add it to a variable using Python?

Tags: python, json

I have a site that takes an userinput e.g. USD and requests data from an API to get exchange rates.
I assign to a variable, var = {'rates': {'DKK': 7.4618}, 'base': 'EUR', 'date': '2020-05-06'}
and want to extract only the specific key (DKK) and it's value to their own variable.

Comment: Perhaps you can edit our question to share the code that you have so far. I'm guessing you've tried something like `var['rates']['DKK']` to get the value of the key.

Answer (score 0):

If your data format is the same as above then you can access in the following way.

```py
DKK = var.get("rates", {}).get('DKK')
```

Answer (score -1):

You can access a dictionaries value by passing the key to the dict.

```
value = var['rates']['DKK']
```